# Error al mostrar variable local en Delphi: "Record, object or class type required"

Tags: delphi

Estoy tratando de mostrar una variable local en un mensaje, pero no tengo claro el concepto.

**Código:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i:integer;
begin
 i:=1;
 ShowMessage(i.AsString);
end;
```

**Error:**

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(31): Record, object or class type required
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 31?

Comment: ShowMessage(i.AsString);

Comment: ¿Funciona si usas `ShowMessage(inttostr(i));`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si funciona, muchas gracias, creía que tocaba definir type o que cosas rara, ya quedo.

Comment: Genial. Lo pondré como respuesta cuando encuentre una referencia que diga que el problema es que `AsString` funciona con objetos o registros pero no con primitivas como `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [documentación de Embarcadero sobre este error](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_need_record_xml.html), se especifica que puede ocurrir por alguno de estos dos motivos:

- Al aplicar la notación '.' a un elemento que no es un objeto, registro, o variable de clase.
- Al usar una variable con el tipo incorrecto en un comando WITH.

No es el segundo caso, sino el primero, porque se intenta aplicar `.AsString` a una variable de tipo `int` que no es un objeto o registro.

Una solución rápida sería usar `inttostr(i)` en lugar de `i.AsString`:

```
ShowMessage(inttostr(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

En versiones modernas de Delphi, puedes utilizar una *notación* bastante similar a la que te está dando error, siempre y cuando hayas incluido la unidad `system.sysutils` dentro de la cláusula `uses` de la unidad que contiene el código, puedes invocar al método `ToString()` sobre una variable de tipo entero, lo qué, tras bambalinas, tirará del [*type helper* `TIntegerHelper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TIntegerHelper), la sintaxis correcta es:

```
implementation
uses system.sysutils;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
  S: string;
begin
  I := 1;
  ShowMessage(I.ToString);
  //además:
  S := '10452';
  if I.tryParse(S) then
    ShowMessage(I.ToHexString);
end;
```

En la documentación puedes encontrar más [ejemplos de los métodos disponibles en los helpers de tipos enteros](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/Integer_Type_Helpers_(Delphi)) y más información de los [*type helpers*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) en general.

Si no incluyes la unidad `sysutils` en la cláusula uses, estos helpers no estarán disponibles para tu código.

Todos los enlaces te llevan a recursos en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que lo que necesitas hacer es cambiar el:

```
  ShowMessage(i.AsString);
```

Por un:

```
  ShowMessage(i.ToString);
```